# Get a substring from a column and perform a groupBy and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot, substring

I have a table that stores data about a large number of files, such as their language, unique ID, file path etc. I want to be able to get the sub-string from the unique ID which gives me the asset type, this is always the first 2 letters of the ID. I then want to group these asset types by language and have a count for how many of each type every language has. So at the end I would ideally like a table that has a language column and then a column for each substring (asset type).

I have tried to create a large switch statement but this isn't very reliable and I was told maybe linq would be better. I don't have much experience with linq or sql and I have a couple of sql queries I've tried that gets me one part of the desired results, but I was hoping maybe someone who has more experience might know how to group these functions into one statement.

```
SELECT 
  LCID,
  SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2)  
FROM [table]
```

this gets me the correct substrings, but I have multiple rows for each language. Is there any way to group the same languages into one column and then count how many of each type there are? Thanks

[image: sample data from current query]
[image: desired results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a `COUNT` and a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2), 
  COUNT(*) Total
FROM [table]
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2)
```

You did not specify what database but, if you are using SQL Server and `LCID` is in your `SELECT` statement, then you will need to include it in your `GROUP BY` clause.

If the `LCID` value is unique for each row then you will get multiple records for each `AssetID` because it will try to group the unique values together.  As a result, I removed the `LCID`.

If it is not unique, then you can use:

```
SELECT LCID, 
  SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2), 
  COUNT(*) Total
FROM [table]
GROUP BY LCID, SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2)
```

Based on the edits that you made, you want a `PIVOT` which transforms the data from rows into columns.  For a `PIVOT` you will use:

```
select LCID, HA, HT, HP, FH, FX
from
(
  SELECT LCID, 
    SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2) AssetID
  FROM [table]
) src
pivot
(
  count(AssetID)
  for AssetID in (HA, HT, HP, FH, FX) -- place more values here
) piv
```

If the values are unknown that you want to transform into columns, then you will need to use dynamic SQL similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2)) 
                    from [table]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT LCID, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT LCID, 
                  SUBSTRING(AssetID,1,2) AssetID
                FROM [table]
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(AssetID)
                for AssetID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: @RebeccaD I edited my answer with a version that includes the `LCID`

Comment: @bluefeet- thanks, that's it almost correct. The only problem I still have it that each LCID is coming up for each asset type. I was hoping to have one row per LCID that includes all the asset types and their count. So the results I have now with your query that includes LCID, only merge the same LCIDs into one row?

Comment: Can you edit your OP with some sample data and the desired result? I think I must be missing something. :)

Comment: Hi I added 2 images, the 1st shows the current results from the query above, the bottom on shows what I would like them to look like.

Comment: Awesome! that seems to produce the result I want :) now I can just implement that into my program hopefully!

Comment: @RebeccaD happy to help.  I also added a dynamic SQL version that could be used if the values to turn to columns is unknown.